# What is a group account?

Tags: ps4

My son's friend said they wanted to put 4 PS4 on the same email. He was telling me this is a smart thing to do to help each other upgrade a player on NBA 2K20

Comment: What do you mean with "put 4 PS4 on the same email"?

Comment: It may mean signing in four different PS4s on the same account